# 'currentApple' is already defined showing in jslint

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, jslint

I have have some js code;
in that I ran the js lint.
I have this error:

> 'currentApple' is already defined

Do I need to remove var `currentApple` from `else` to make it work?

I'm providing my code below:

```
if(appleTab == Lifeline){
    var currentApple = appleWorklist.getcurrentAppleTime("currentAppointmentcurrentAppleTime");
    fo.allApples = currentApple;
}
else
{
    var currentApple = appleWorklist.getcurrentAppleTime("CalendarcurrentAppointmentcurrentAppleTime");
    fo.allApples = currentApple;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var currentApple;
if (appleTab == Lifeline) {
    currentApple = /* etc. */
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no blockscope in javascript, so `currentApple` in your code snippet is basically the same thingy.

[from Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)'s  bible, paragraph Variables:

> JavaScript does not have block scope, so defining variables in blocks
>   can confuse programmers who are experienced with other C family
>   languages. Define all variables at the top of the function.

Just declare every used variable once with a var statement at the start of your function.